# Should imported protobuf have options in gRPC?

Tags: import, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I tried to find the answer in the documentation but I could not.
I am new in gRPC and proto files and maybe is very basic question, sorry for that.

I have two files at same directory level

```
- mainProto.proto
- importedProto.proto
```

the main proto includes the options

```proto
option csharp_namespace = "business.products.accounts";
option go_package = "protobuf/com/bbva/business.accounts;products";
option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.bbva.business.products.accounts";
```

And the **importedProto** does not have options. They are **at same package**.
Do I need declare the same options in imported proto ??

Again sorry this is a basic question but I could not find the answer and logic tells me not because are in same package but if another package includes it it will inherit the options from the other main proto buf ? or each protofile can have different options ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options only apply to the file/message/field/service/rpc they are placed within. So the options at the top-level of a file only apply to the file, not the package. You need to repeat the options for each file.

Protoc can generate code for a single file at a time. If one file's options could impact another that would mean you'd get different results depending on which files you generate together in a single invocation of protoc. To address that, protoc would have to require that all protos within a package are generated at a time, which isn't the case. Protoc is much more akin to C/C++ where each file may be compiled separately and the package is just a namespacing mechanism.

Comment: Thanks, dude, I get it now.